# nested 'and' condition in python 'if statement'

Tags: python, python-3.x

I used nested 'and' condition in python 'if statement'  as below,

```
a=[3.93, 3.90, 3.92, 3.91]

if (a[0] and a[1])==3.90 and (a[2] and a[3])==3.91:

    print(True)

else:

    print(False)
```

While executing the code it produces the result as 'True'.

But it needs to produce 'false' since a[2] and a[3] are not equal to 3.91 as well as a[0] and a[1] are not equal to 3.90.

May I know the reason and the correct code?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, programming languages require more precision than the English language. To get what you want, do this:

```
if a[0] == 3.90 and a[1] == 3.90 and a[2] == 3.91 and a[3]==3.91:
```

The code you started with is going to do a "truthy" test on (for example) a[0] and a[1] – and then return a[1] since they are both "true". Therefore, `(a[0] and a[1])` will be `3.90`. So, the first part of the conditional evaluates True – and for this same reason, so does the second part.

Answer (score 0):

the problem with your code is that you are forgetting to include a[0] == (value) and a[2] == (value) within your if statement. completely leaving them out of the question.

fix- include a[0] and a[2] within if statement.

```
a=[3.93, 3.90, 3.92, 3.91]

if a[0]==3.90 and a[1]==3.90 and a[2]==3.91 and a[3]==3.91:
     value = True
else:
     value = False
print(value)
```